# pandas error when convert object to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

This is two lines of inputdataframe:

```
    ts  country       os product_id  total_users  total_purchases
0  0000-00-00   Brazil      iOS                       1                0
1  0000-00-00  Germany                                1                0
```

I have tried following commands in order to convert 'ts' which is object to datetime:

```
 df['ts'] = df['ts'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

and this is an error I've got:
**ValueError: Month out of range in datetime string "0000-00-00"**

I know that there is a problem with 0000-00-00, but I don't know how to get ride of it and solve it to work?

Comment: What datetime are you expecting 0000-00-00 to resolve to?

Comment: Well it's outside of the range so you need to decide what to do with these dates

Comment: to convert it to Nan.. I need to clean my data..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

easy peasy

```
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'], errors ='coerce')
```

no need to clean the data. wrong timestamps will get the `NaT` (not a timestamp)

Comment: My doubt is that in practice do i keep Nat or not? and if so, how would be possible to replace Nat with empty?